# how to get current month and year

Tags: asp.net

Can anybody tell me that how I can get current month and year and show it in a label in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 74):

If you have following two labels:

```
<asp:Label ID="MonthLabel" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="YearLabel" runat="server" />
```

Than you can use following code just need to set the Text Property for these labels like:

```
MonthLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
YearLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
```

Answer (score 48):

Use the DateTime.Now property. This returns a DateTime object that contains a Year and Month property (both are integers).

```
string currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
string currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

monthLabel.Text = currentMonth;
yearLabel.Text = currentYear;
```

Comment: What happens if the first line executes on December 31 at 23.59.59.999 and the second line executes on January 1 already? You will get currentMonth = 12 and currentYear = new year number, which is incorrect...

Comment: @John good point. in that case I think you can store the `dateTime` in a variable first. `DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string currentMonth = now.Month.ToString();
            string currentYear = now.Year.ToString();`

Answer (score 27):

Like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM yyyy")
```

For more information, see [DateTime Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: Used with inline code is nice and easy.
    <%=DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM yyyy")%>

Answer (score 14):

```
    public string GetCurrentYear()
    {
        string CurrentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

        return CurrentYear;
    }

    public string GetCurrentMonth()
    {
        string CurrentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();

        return CurrentMonth;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question but adding an explanation of the code would be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 10):

```cs
label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
```

and

```cs
label2.Text = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this:

```
<p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
```

Answer (score 7):

Find Current Year
Using Razor try this

```
@DateTime.Now.Year
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Globalization;

LblMonth.Text = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();

DateTimeFormatInfo dinfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
int month = Convert.ToInt16(LblMonth.Text);

LblMonth.Text = dinfo.GetMonthName(month);
```