# How do I get the current year in c#?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I have a plugin for auto numbering in my CRM instance. Basically, the prefix is the current year. So I want it to work like this, if the year is not current, update it with the current year.

`new_prefix` is the field that has the year in it that I need to change if different than current year. The plug-in currently works I just wanna change the year if it's different. Also this keeps telling me it's too much code and too little details.

```csh
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace UGKCK.CRM.PlugIns
{
    public class AutoNumbering : IPlugin
    {
        #region Secure/Unsecure Configuration Setup
        private string _secureConfig = null;
        private string _unsecureConfig = null;

        public AutoNumbering(string unsecureConfig, string secureConfig)
        {
            _secureConfig = secureConfig;
            _unsecureConfig = unsecureConfig;
        }
        #endregion
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            ITracingService tracer = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            OrganizationServiceContext orgService = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);

            try
            {
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                Entity autoNumberingRecord = RetrieveAutoNumbering(orgService, entity);
                UpdateNumber(service, autoNumberingRecord, entity);
                UpdateNextNumber(service, autoNumberingRecord);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private Entity RetrieveAutoNumbering(OrganizationServiceContext orgService, Entity entity)
        {
            Entity retrievedAutoNumber = (from an in orgService.CreateQuery("new_autonumbering")
                                          where (String)an["new_entity"] == entity.LogicalName
                                          select an).FirstOrDefault();

            Entity autoNumber = new Entity("new_autonumbering");
            autoNumber.Id = retrievedAutoNumber.Id;
            autoNumber["new_prefix"] = retrievedAutoNumber["new_prefix"];
            autoNumber["new_nextnumber"] = retrievedAutoNumber["new_nextnumber"];

            return autoNumber;
        }

        private void UpdateNumber(IOrganizationService service, Entity autoNumberingRecord, Entity target)
        {
            var prefix = autoNumberingRecord.Attributes["new_prefix"].ToString();
            var number = autoNumberingRecord.Attributes["new_nextnumber"].ToString();

            if (target.LogicalName == "new_servicerequest")
            {

                target["new_servicerequestnumber"] = prefix + "-" + number;
            }
            else if (target.LogicalName == "contact")
            {

                target["new_contactnumber"] = prefix + "-" + number;
            }
            service.Update(target);
        }

        private void UpdateNextNumber(IOrganizationService service, Entity autoNumberingRecord)
        {
            var currentNumber = (int)autoNumberingRecord.Attributes["new_nextnumber"];
            var nextNumber = currentNumber + 1;

            autoNumberingRecord["new_nextnumber"] = nextNumber;
            service.Update(autoNumberingRecord);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the system date and split day, month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986114/get-the-system-date-and-split-day-month-and-year)

Comment: I honestly don't know where to start. Do I need a certain library or something?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I need to get the current year. Not format a date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get current month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890956/how-to-get-current-month-and-year)

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime.Now.Year` will give you the current year.

Since you seem to be OK with using this plugin to handle its normal autonumbering tasks, plus dynamically update the prefix, what you could do is add a method to check the prefix and if necessary set it to the current year before doing anything else.

```csh
private void setPrefix(Entity autoNumberingRecord)
{
    var year = DateTime.Now.Year;

    if(autoNumberingRecord["new_prefix"] != year)
    {
        autoNumberingRecord["new_prefix"] = year;
    }           
}
```

Then call it from your main try clause:

```csh
Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
Entity autoNumberingRecord = RetrieveAutoNumbering(orgService, entity);
setPrefix(autoNumberingRecord);
UpdateNumber(service, autoNumberingRecord, entity);
UpdateNextNumber(service, autoNumberingRecord);
```

This way the prefix is set properly when you update the number on the target record, and when you update the autoNumberingRecord.

Since you always want the prefix to be the current year, you could just set it every time, but I guess if you're auditing the record or something, you might want to avoid setting that field unless necessary.

All the being said, I would probably take the approach of using early bound classes and adding a property called Prefix to the AutoNumberingRecord class, which would include the comparison and update logic for the new_prefix field.