# How to get current year in master page template

Tags: kentico

I want to display the current year for copyright under the footer. This footer resides in the master page template. I tried to use a macro but it doesn't work.

```
    <div class="col-4"><%= CurrentDateTime.Year %></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASCX layout macros are not supported. You need to use standard ASP.Net approach. For example something like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890956/how-to-get-current-month-and-year). So, using `<%: DateTime.Now.Year %>` should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Or if the template is the HTML type of layout, you can sue this macro instead:

```
{% Now.Year %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest placing a web part zone in that area where you have the DateTime attempting to be rendered and putting a static text web part in the zone with the macro of `{%Now.Year%}`.

Placing any code in the layout of the template will cause problems if not done correctly so use the basic functionality of Kentico.